# (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 16-17: truncated \uXXXX escape

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to import one module of pyusb library that is in the **d:\pyusb-1.0.0a2\usb**. So first of all I must add its path to `sys.path`. But I receive the below error.

Note : I successfully can import `d:\pyusb-1.0.0a2` !!!

```
Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 10:38:22) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('d:\pyusb-1.0.0a2\usb')
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 16-17: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use a raw string

```
>>> sys.path.append(r'd:\pyusb-1.0.0a2\usb')
```

or escape the backslashes

```
>>> sys.path.append('d:\\pyusb-1.0.0a2\\usb')
```

or use forward slashes

```
>>> sys.path.append('d:/pyusb-1.0.0a2/usb')
```

Otherwise, Python will try to interpret `\usb` as a Unicode escape sequence (like `\uBEEF`) which fails for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I got the syntaxError when add the file upload method in flask as follows,

```
    def upload():
         if request.method == 'POST':
             f = request.files['file']
             basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
             print(basepath)
             upload_path = os.path.join(basepath, 'static\files',secure_filename(f.filename))
             f.save(upload_path)
             return redirect(url_for('upload'))
         return render_template('upload.html')
```

The console shows error as follows:

```
upload_path = os.path.join(basepath,r'static\files',secure_filename(f.filename))
```

So,I think it caused by '\u' in Unicode Escape Sequence,we should use raw strings to fix it.

```
upload_path = os.path.join(basepath,r'static\files',secure_filename(f.filename))
```